# What code is used for dynamically shrinking navbars as you scroll down?

Tags: jquery

I have looking to duplicate this navbar for my site:

http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/

As you can see, when scrolling down, the navbar shrinks, what script is used for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {      // Runs when page is scrolled
  var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();        
  if (y > 100) {
    jQuery('nav').css('height', '80px');  // Changes after scroll distance of 100px
  } else {
    jQuery('nav').css('height', '200px'); // Reverts back when close to top
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Spence, but do you know what this is called? So I can fetch a script form codepen or somewhere?

Comment: I'd call it something like... "dynamic resizing of menu on scroll"

Comment: Here's a resource you might want to check out: http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll